# Selenium returns a Blank page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access this url with selenium but it gives a blank page but when i open the url manually on my browser it works fine.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
def scrape_website(url):
    options = Options()
    options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
    preferences = {"safebrowsing.enabled": "false"}
    options.add_argument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server')
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Page Title:", driver.title)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()

url = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/buy/in-canberra+-+greater+region,+act/list-1'
scrape_website(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add Webdriver executable path like,

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver', options=options)`

You can also read about [Webdriver Manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#use-with-chrome) for details about Webdriver and its application.

Comment: this is not the problem. Selenium detects the driver automatically.The web driver launches but i get a blank page.